# Local notification not arriving

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am running background codes to check if there is any changes to a website and if there is a change a local notification to alert the user. However, when i run the code and try it out the local notification does not arrive.
This is the code in my appDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Has Entered Background");
    timerCountDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(backGroundParsing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)backGroundParsing {
    //This is where my background checking happens. I deleted the code here to make it shorter.
    if (totalNumberOfEvents > totalNumberOfEvetsRecorded) {
                                NSLog(@"Notificatoin sent");
                                NSString *finalNumberOfEventsRecorded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalNumberOfEvents];
                                NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                [userDefaults setObject:finalNumberOfEventsRecorded forKey:@"finalRegisteredNumberOfEvents"];
                                UILocalNotification *notifyUserAboutNewEvent = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setAlertBody:@"New event has been organised"];
                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notifyUserAboutNewEvent]];
                            }
}
```

I do log "Notification sent" but i do not receive any notification. Is there something missing or something wrong? I do not have any other code in my other void actions.

EDIT
After what @rckoenes had said i edited my code to this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication * _Nonnull)application
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {
    [self backGroundParsing];
}

- (void)backGroundParsing {
    //This is where my background checking happens. I deleted the code here to make it shorter.
                            if (totalNumberOfEvents > totalNumberOfEvetsRecorded) {
                                NSLog(@"Notificatoin sent");
                                NSString *finalNumberOfEventsRecorded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalNumberOfEvents];
                                NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                [userDefaults setObject:finalNumberOfEventsRecorded forKey:@"finalRegisteredNumberOfEvents"];
                                UILocalNotification *notifyUserAboutNewEvent = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
                                [notifyUserAboutNewEvent setAlertBody:@"New event has been organised"];
                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notifyUserAboutNewEvent]];
                            }
                        });
     }];
    [searchEventsTask resume];
}
```

However, i still do not receive the notification. I am getting an warning when i simulate the background fetch. This is the warning appearing in my NSLog `Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.`
Is this warning normal when i simulate background fetch? My notification still does not appear. How would i fix it?

Comment: You can't user timers in the background. You set the `UILocalNotification` when the app enters the background and use the `fireDate` to delay the notification with 60 seconds.

Comment: But if i dont use timer it will only check for changes only once

Comment: Yes just call the `backGroundParsing` from the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and it should work.

Comment: but won't it call it only once

Comment: Sorry what do you mean call it only once?

Comment: because if i don't use the timer, the code will run once and will never be repeated again

Comment: True, on iOS you can't keep you app running in the background. Only media players, voip client, accessory companion app or location based apps are allowed to run. You register for background fetch, but this is really restricted. With the background tech the OS will allow you app the fetch data, but if you use to much battery it will not allow you app to update any more. You should really use some kind of server side solution.

Comment: I tried to put the notification part of the code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` but it did not work. I think the problem is with the way I call the notification rather than where i place it. I just tried to do it without the if statement and the notification did not appear

Comment: I am only calling it once every few hours to minimise battery usage

Comment: Yes but you can't because app don't run in the background and timers are not working when you app is going in the background. There are many thread on this. You will need a serverside solution. And you timer is now calling every minute and not every hour. But it will not work period.

Comment: You best option is: [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56l) good luck

Comment: But now the problem is the notification

Comment: No the problem is that you timer will not work, You are only allowed to execute a lengthy task for max 10 minutes. Or your app will have to user one of the background modes, which are restricted to media players, voip client, accessory companion app or location based apps. If you app is not in any of these categories then you might try background fetch, linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8+, you have to user's permission for local notifications. Add the following line in your `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge| UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
```